# If exist Update else Insert Into. MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm asking this question in order to find the best practice to do it.

```
DB::table('owners')
   ->where('property_id',$id)
   ->update(array('person_id'=>$owner));
```

The problem is that in the table `owners` might not have a row to update. In that occasion i need to make an `INSERT INTO` instead of `UPDATE`.

My problem is that i have to run 2 queries each time, one for checking if the row already exists, and one more to `update` or `insert into`. Is it right to run 2 queries each time? Is  there a better way to achieve that? I need to keep the queering processes fast  for the user.

**UPDATE:** The table `owners` is a middle table of a many to many relationship. Unfortunately i cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Could you not make a compound unique key from the foreign ids in the table and *then* use on duplicate key update?

Comment: @CD001 Ok, i need a little help about that :-)

Comment: I'd have to test it but the theory goes like this: you can create a unique index on 2 columns (the 2 foreign ids in your link table) - then when you INSERT you'll set both the owner and the property... if those 2 attributes match your unique compound key then `ON DUPLICATE KEY ... UPDATE` can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you could try to use `firstOrCreate` method of Laravel to check if user exists. After that retrieve the user object and pass it to an update function else if the user is not found `firstOrCreate` method will take care of you as it will create a new user with the data you will provide and will auto increment last user + 1 id.

There is also the option to use `firstOrNew` which will check if an instance exists based on the array values you passed and if no match is found it will auto create a new instance of the model you are handling for further manipulation.

Here is example with `firstOrNew`

## Example Controller file.

```
public function getFirstUserOrNew($email)
   {

      $user = User::firstOrNew(['email' => $email]);

      if($user)
      {
        $this->UpdateUser($user);
      }
      else
      {
       $this->CreateUser($user);
      }
   }

    public function UpdateUser(User $user)
    {
      //Do update stuff
    }
    
    public function CreateUser(User $user)
    {
      //Do create stuff
    }
```

P.S - I'm from Greece, if you want to discuss anything in native language send me a PM :)

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Pyton contribution It seems you can also use an `updateOrCreate` method as it is explained [here](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updateOrCreate).

Comment: Very nice approach! (Thank you! - Ευχαριστώ πολύ!)

Comment: No problem, you could always use [mutators and accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to reduce the duplication of your code or even create a [repository](http://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) for your models. Τίποτα φίλος ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Update or Insert row You can use `updateOrCreate`

```
$owner = Owner::updateOrCreate(['property_id' => $id], ['person_id'=>$owner]);
```

Comment: Is this an actual method? I've not seen this in the documentation.
Can you point me to a reference link please?

Comment: Documentation of L5 is poor. Taylor on L5.1 release  will update docs.

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updateOrCreate

Explore Eloquent/Model and Builder to find interesting methods :)

Comment: Note that updateOrCreate() is actually a convenience method for running firstOrNew() and then save(), and so is therefore firing two queries instead of one.